# Has anyone heard about a replacement for the Concept Expansion service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I have been learning about the IBM Watson services and Bluemix over the last few months. I had previously looked at the Concept Expansion service but when I returned to the [page](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/concept-expansion.html) where this service is described, I found the message from IBM that this service was being withdrawn:
[image: Announcement that the Concept Expansion Service is being withdrawn]
Has anyone seen or heard of an alternative or replacement being suggested or offered by IBM?

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent is [Concept Insights](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/concept-insights.html). It works by making graphs of concepts in a corpus, with each concept having a path within that graph. Many of the Concept Insights APIs are for searching text documents, but you can use the [related_concepts endpoint](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/concept-insights/api/v2/#get_document_state) to expand a concept. For example, the following queries concepts related to IBM Watson and Business:

```
curl -u "{username}":"{ci-password}" -G -d "concepts=[\"/graphs/wikipedia/en-latest/concepts/IBM_Watson\",\"/graphs/wikipedia/en-latest/concepts/Business\"]&level=1&limit=2" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/concept-insights/api/v2/graphs/wikipedia/en-latest/related_concepts"
```

returns this:

```
{
  "concepts": [
    {
      "score":0.7795701,
      "concept": {
        "id":"/graphs/wikipedia/en-20120601/concepts/Business_intelligence",
        "label":"Business intelligence"
      }
    },
    {
      "score":0.7564283,
      "concept": {
        "id":"/graphs/wikipedia/en-20120601/concepts/Data_model",
        "label":"Data model"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

which distills down to "Business Intelligence" and "Data model".

Answer (score 0):

Concept Insights is retired. I am now using AlchemyLanguage and this is working adequately for my needs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13438519)

Comment: Hi Liam, I'm afraid that my original question has been "OBE", i.e. Overtaken By Events. Namely, IBM is moving very quickly to update their offerings for Watson Cognitive Services offered on their Bluemix platform. The replacement is AlchemyLanguage services, also on the Bluemix platform (see https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language.html). Does this help to clarify my comment on my original question?

Comment: This has been flagged for review. I merely reviewed it. As it stands I'd say this isn't an answer (TBF the question is off topic as well). Basically I'd turn this into a comment.