# Can Watson Cluster list of words by category

Tags: ibm-watson

Hi we try to to see if Watson can generate this feature : 
Given a list of words, build a categorical tree with a predefined branching factor. 
E.g., having a restaurant menu in a list, build a tree with at most 5 children at each 
parent node, where each node is a particular category.
Does anyone knows if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Watson Concept Insights. The related_concepts method is a close match to your requested feature.

Answer (score -1):

You could do that using Concept Expansion (see [Has anyone heard about a replacement for the Concept Expansion service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523864/has-anyone-heard-about-a-replacement-for-the-concept-expansion-service/36548391))

But since this service is going to be closed, I suggest you to try [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/) instead.